# Styling Individual Rows on Tables

Tags: html, css, tabular

Our designer created this table layout for a SPA we're developing. The question we have is, is this achievable with CSS using an HTML table? Specifically we're having issues with the combination of the row spacing (10px), corner radius on individual rows (6px), and the slight drop shadow on the bottom edge of each row.  Each row has 5 cells.

[image: Table screenshot]

Comment: Yes this can be achieved.

Comment: How do you achieve the drop shadow? box-shadow css doesn't work with <tr>

Comment: apply `display: block` to the `tr` and a `min-width` and `min-height` to the `td` and `th`. box-shadow only works on block or inline-block elements.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the CSS property `box-shadow` [applies to all elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) and hence it also works with the `<tr>` tag:

```css
body{
  background-color:#f8f8f8
}
tr{
  display:block;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:0;
  border-radius:6px;
  box-shadow:-1px 3px 2px #bbb;
  margin-bottom:10px
}
td{
  padding:25px
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Particularly,

> the combination of the row spacing (10px), corner radius on individual rows (6px), and the slight drop shadow on the bottom edge of each row

are achieved with the last three lines of CSS style for the tag `tr`, not in the same order. As in another comment, the `display:block` property for the rows `tr` is crucial here.

The above code is valid HTML5 and CSS3.